# Add a variable while reading in and merging multi-files

Tags: r, merge, path, dplyr

I would like to merge several files. These are my paths:

```
allpaths=c("c:\data\country_GM2\GM_2020_8.csv","c:\data\country_GM2\GM_2020_9.csv","c:\data\country_GM2\GM_2020_10.csv","c:\data\country_GM2\GM_2020_11.csv","c:\data\country_GM2\GM_2020_12.csv")
```

I wrote a function like this:

```
merge_1 = function(filepath) {
  datalist= lapply(filepath,
                   function(x){read.csv(file = x, 
                                        header = TRUE, 
                                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)})
  Reduce(function(x,y){rbind.fill(x,y)},datalist)
}

data <-merge_1(allpaths)
```

However, I hope, while I read in each file, I can at the same time add a variable with year and month from the file paths.

For example, for those rows read in from "GM_2020_12.csv", adding a variable with the value "2020.12."

I would appreciate for some hints.
So far, I can only think of, "mutate" in tidyverse package may be the solution, but I haven't found a right way to put it in my function.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column while reading the data extracting the year and month value using regex.

Change the function to :

```
merge_1 = function(filepath) {
  datalist= lapply(filepath,function(x) {
    transform(read.csv(file = x,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
              year_month = sub('.*?(\\d+)_(\\d+)\\.csv$', '\\1.\\2', x))
              })
  Reduce(function(x,y){rbind.fill(x,y)},datalist)
}

data <-merge_1(allpaths)
```

where `sub` returns year and month value from filename.

```
allpaths=c("C:\\data\\country_GM2\\GM_2020_8.csv",
           "C:\\data\\country_GM2\\GM_2020_9.csv")

sub('.*?(\\d+)_(\\d+)\\.csv$', '\\1.\\2', allpaths)
#[1] "2020.8" "2020.9"
```